# how to use onchange event under javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have a code to add row dynamically and submit data to mysql. to achieve this i am using JavaScript code below

```
<script  src="jquery.min.js"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        var addDiv = $('#addinput');
        var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

        $('#addNew').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><select id="p_new" name="stockid[]' + i +'" <?php echo $item; ?></select> <select name="desc[]' + i +'" <?php echo $description; ?></select><a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
                i++;


                return false;
        });

        $('#remNew').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});

</script>
```

its working fine but now i want to update `$description` as i select `$item`.

`$item` and `$description` are from a same table.

i have a code which can simply update description as i select item.
here is php code

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form1">
<table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="150">Country</td>
    <td  width="150"><select name="stockid[]' + i +'" onChange="getCity('onchange.php?    
     stockid='+this.value)"><?php echo $item; ?></select></td>


  </tr>
  <tr style="">
    <td>City</td>
    <td ><div id="citydiv"><select name="desc"><option>Select City</option></select></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is javascript code

```
<script>
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
    }



    function getCity(strURL) {      

        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {                        
                        document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }

    }
</script>
```

its working fine but when i use

```
<select name="stockid[]' + i +'" onChange="getCity('onchange.php?    
         stockid='+this.value)"><?php echo $item; ?></select>
```

above code in first javascript file insted of

```
<select id="p_new" name="stockid[]' + i +'" <?php echo $item; ?></select>
```

its not working please help me hot to autoupdate description field according to item selection.....

Comment: shouldn't it be onchange instead of onChange.

Comment: what is the content of your `$item` variable be sure it contains `<option></option>` tags with a value property

Comment: `$item = '';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getitem))
{
  $item .= '<option value = "'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['stock_id']. " - ".$row['description'].'</option>';
}`
 this is my item code

Comment: This is a mess? You're using jQuery, but still not using it for ajax, where it's really great, and you're using inline event handlers, and the jQuery event handlers you have are using live() which have been deprecated and removed from jQuery, and ....

Comment: i just want to know how to use `<select name="stockid[]' + i +'" onChange="getCity('onchange.php?    
         stockid='+this.value)"><?php echo $item; ?></select>` code in the first javascript code.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use variables in html statment, I am talking about [i] variable. what is this variable for?

```
<select id="p_new" name="stockid[]' + i +'" <?php echo $item; ?></select>
```